# Backup of apps and their settings

Tags: backup, google-backup

I learned about Titanium Backup but I don't have a rooted device yet.

I'd still like to backup all my installed apps and their settings - will the default Google backup:

[image]

What does this backup exactly?

Sorry if this has been answered before but I really couldn't find it on quick search. So maybe it won't hurt to have my post here.

I see that my best option is adb ([Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices)) though... but I still don't know what the default Google backup does then... and why it's not enough...

Answer (score -1):

install Helium - App Sync and Backup & APK Extractor (to backup your APK) from playstore it might help you but it will not save your settings

Comment: ok, I'll check it out... BUT still I want to know what does this normal backup do then - nothing at all?

Comment: well this funtion will not create any apk backups it will save your wifi settings nd password, sync can help you with Contacts, Email, Calendars, Chrome Browser Data, Google Talk Chat Logs, apps & purchased apps etc.. sms backup is not possible if u want to backup photos you need google+

Comment: ok. "apps & purchased apps" -> what do you mean by that? Does it mean I'm able to automatically install all the apps I had installed on the old device, just without settings?

Comment: Any apps you have purchased (or installed) are linked with your Google account. When you set up a new Android device (or enter your account after resetting your Android phone or tablet to factory default settings), Android will offer to automatically download and install the apps you previously had installed. You can also view apps you have previously installed in the Google Play app, so you won’t forget which apps you have used (or purchased). Other content you purchase from Google Play is also tied to your Google account.

Comment: Yes, thank you.. but that's why I asked - why did you mention "apps & purchased apps" there if that is already by default - or maybe it isn't? But I believe I had apps under My Apps in PlayStore on the web even before I turned on backup option. Another thing: you recommend APK Extractor and it doesn't save settings - so what do I gain if app list is saved already?

Comment: Well I recomment APK Extractor Because with the help of that app you can backup or extract apk of each apps which will be saved on SD Card so that you can install it again any time. so you dont have to download it again and waste you precious data & time. About "apps & purchased apps" i explained it above

Comment: ok, thank you, now I see... so I guess that backing up application settings won't be possible though... until I have a rooted device.

Comment: I still think your answer includes some things that are already backed up without enabling that option, for example: Contacts, Email, Calendars, Chrome Browser Data (if signed in), Google Talk Chat Logs, apps & purchased apps ... I mean actually everything here should be already backed up. Chat logs are saved on the server by default.. as is email and contacts of course... So still not sure what this does.

Comment: I dont this so. Its a Small App (193kb) give it a try. well save all those contacts, emails, calenders etc you have to enable you account & sync option in the settings http://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/android-google-sync.png